# Appending matching column onto each result row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm not a SQL veteran so please excuse me if this is obvious; I'm learning.

I have two tables in a database for a wedding invite system; guests and invites. One invite (invitation) can contain many guests.

For purposes of creating a mail merge for the invites, I'm trying to select the firstname and lastname from the guest table, where the guest's inviteID is the same as the others; effectively returning on row of data containing the inviteID's data and a column each for the names of the guests.

My problem is I can return the data, but across multiple rows which won't work for the mail-merge. I can create a PHP script to do a work-around, but I would like to learn how this could be achieved in pure SQL.

Can anybody shed some light? Can this be done? Is this sheer madness?

Hoping to achieve:

```
***************************  1. row ***************************
       inviteID: 39
  inviteURLSlug: thewinnetts
                ....
guestFirstName1: Sid
  guestSurname1: Winnett
guestFirstName2: Claire
  guestSurname2: Winnett
```

'invite' table:

```
+---------------------+--------------+
| Field               | Type         |
+---------------------+--------------+
| inviteID            | int(11)      |
| inviteURLSlug       | varchar(64)  |
| inviteQRValue       | varchar(255) |
| inviteQRImageURL    | varchar(255) |
| inviteAddress1      | varchar(32)  |
| inviteAddress2      | varchar(32)  |
| inviteAddress3      | varchar(32)  |
| inviteCity          | varchar(32)  |
| inviteCounty        | varchar(32)  |
| inviteCountry       | varchar(32)  |
| invitePostcode      | varchar(16)  |
| inviteDateSend      | datetime     |
| inviteDateResponded | datetime     |
| inviteCreated       | datetime     |
| inviteUpdated       | timestamp    |
+---------------------+--------------+
```

'guest' table:

```
+-------------------+--------------+
| Field             | Type         |
+-------------------+--------------+
| guestID           | int(11)      |
| inviteID          | int(11)      |
| guestFirstName    | varchar(32)  |
| guestSurname      | varchar(32)  |
| guestSide         | varchar(8)   |
| guestAttending    | tinyint(1)   |
| guestEmail        | varchar(255) |
| guestPhone        | varchar(32)  |
| guestMobile       | varchar(16)  |
| guestAddress1     | varchar(32)  |
| guestAddress2     | varchar(32)  |
| guestAddress3     | varchar(32)  |
| guestCity         | varchar(32)  |
| guestCounty       | varchar(32)  |
| guestCountry      | varchar(32)  |
| guestPostCode     | varchar(16)  |
| guestProfilePhoto | varchar(64)  |
| guestFoodVeg      | tinyint(1)   |
| guestFoodReq      | varchar(255) |
| guestTwitter      | varchar(15)  |
| guestFacebook     | varchar(32)  |
| guestPlusone      | int(1)       |
| guestCreated      | datetime     |
| guestUpdated      | timestamp    |
+-------------------+--------------+
```

Failed Join attempt and cropped results sample:

```
SELECT * FROM guest INNER JOIN invite on guest.inviteID = invite.inviteID \G


*************************** 64. row ***************************
            guestID: 72
           inviteID: 39
     guestFirstName: Claire
       guestSurname: Winnett
                    .......
*************************** 65. row ***************************
            guestID: 73
           inviteID: 39
     guestFirstName: Sid
       guestSurname: Winnett
                    .......
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: have you tried using a JOIN ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have added a snapshot of an INNER JOIN which places each result on separate rows, I want to "group" these so each guests names would appear on a single row, based upon an inviteID. A sample of the desired result data is shown at the top in the original post - do I need to clarify anything for you?

Comment: @Dagon ^ please see above comment. (I couldn't @ more than one user)

Comment: when you mention "1. row", do you mean that you expect all the results to be on a single line?.

Comment: @PatomaS I would like to list one invite per row/line, and within each line list the names of all the guests that are part of this invite. I have since been trying to use a subquery with GROUP_CONCAT() with no success.

Comment: I just updated my query to adjust it to what I think you are asking. But I'm not entirely sure yet.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve those results will require additional processing in PHP.
To do so, modify your query to this:

```
SELECT i.*,
  g.guestFirstName,
  g.guestSurname
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.guestFirstName, '|', g.guestSurname ORDER BY g.guestSurname DESC) AS names
FROM invite i
INNER JOIN guest g ON i.inviteID = g.inviteID;
```

making sure to return your results as an **array**.  From there, convert the concatenated results into an array then iterate through them to set the custom key name and corresponding value (assumes your query results are in array format with the variable name $queryresults):

```
$names = explode(',' $queryresults['names']);
unset($queryresults['names']);

$i = 1;
foreach ($names as $name) {
  $split_name = str_split("|", $name);
  $queryresults['guestFirstName' . $i] = $split_name[0];
  $queryresults['guestSurname' . $i] = $split_name[1];
  $i++;
}
```

This should give you your desired results.

Comment: Thats helpful @brandonsmith , but I think I havnt made myself clear in what I was after, so I appended some more info above under "Hoping to achieve"

Comment: Thanks for this. I have already made a script with is suprisingly similar, but I was hoping to achieve the same with just SQL (for my own education/OCD). I am growing to feel I have been somewhat over ambitious!

Comment: It could be achieved using a stored procedure, but that's even more tedious. That kind of structure is better fit for a NoSQL database, ex. documents in MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

SQL is not good at this sort of thing. It wants to work in sets, where all the items in the set are the same. You are asking for two items within the set to be smooshed together. Here is a possible solution:

```
SELECT
  t1.inviteID, 
  t1.guestID, 
  t1.guestFirstName, 
  t1.guestSurname, 
  t2.guestFirstName AS guestFirstName2, 
  t2.guestSurname AS guestSurname2
FROM
  guests as t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  guests as t2
ON t1.inviteID = t2.inviteID
AND t1.guestID <> t2.guestID
WHERE 
 t1.guestID = (select min(t3.guestID) from guests as t3 where t3.inviteID = t1.inviteID)
;
```

The `guests` table is used twice, once to provide the first guest on each invite, and a second time, using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to provide the second. The `LEFT OUTER` ensures you still get the first even if there isn't a second. The other criteria are there to ensure you don't join a row to itself, and you only output the firsts, with the seconds attached (and not the other way around).

[Here is a sample fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7c32/11) (in MySQL)

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what you are looking for?

Updated after your comment.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT `guest`.`guestFirstName`,`guest`.`guestSurname`, `invite`.`inviteURLSlug` ) FROM `guest`
LEFT JOIN `invite` ON `invite`.`inviteID` = `guest`.`inviteID`
WHERE `invite`.`inviteID` = 5
```

I just made two simple tables with minimal information for testing, but is easily expandable to whatever you have/want.

You are going to have some fields repeated since the number of rows is going to be related to the number of guests.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I have been troubling to explain - thanks for bearing with me. The last hurdle (if this is possible) is to repeat this for each inviteID, i.e.: "WHERE invite.inviteID = 1; ...WHERE invite.inviteID = 2; ...WHERE invite.inviteID = 3; " and so on. Is this possible?

Comment: for that you will need that number to be variable, you can do that in a procedure; set a variable and use it after the equal sign. Then to execute the thing you will call the procedure.